# Declare variable and use in AWS Redshift query

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am trying to declare a variable and use in my query.

I have a query like this:

```
INSERT into segmentation (import_date, id, orders, qty, value)
SELECT
    '2024-01-01'::DATE AS import_date,
    td.id,
    COUNT(DISTINCT td.date) AS total_orders,
    SUM(td.qty) AS total_qty,
    SUM(td.amount) AS total_value
FROM
    customer_actions td
WHERE
    td.date_trading_nk <= '2024-01-01'::DATE
GROUP BY
    td.id;
```

There are few other conditions in where condition I need to apply but have to use the same date `'2024-01-01'::DATE`. Is it possible to declare a parameter and use all the places rather than hardcode the date

I have tried as below two options to declare it but it doesn't work.

Option #1:

```
DECLARE param_date DATE := '2024-01-01';
```

Option #2:

```
WITH parameter_date AS 
(
    SELECT '2024-02-25'::DATE AS param_date
)
```

Comment: The use of variables is normally the responsibility of the app or SQL client that sends the SQL query to the database -- it isn't standard SQL. Can you tell us what problems you have with using Option #2? What do you mean by "it doesn't work"?

Answer (score 0):

As John Rotenstein said replacing parameters into the SQL is the usually the responsibility of a layer outside of Redshift.  Most benches allow you to do this but in their own syntax.

If I understand the intent of the question you want to issue the same SQL but have the date be a parameter set elsewhere (for some unstated reason).  You cannot DECLARE a variable in Redshift as you have seen.  You can use a WITH clause but it is part of the SELECT statement and I suspect you are trying to make it an independent statement which isn't how this clause is used.

You could define a stored procedure and give the date as a parameter when calling the the procedure.  This will work but since the date is written in the same statement I'm not sure this meets you needs.

You could define a temp table with the date like:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE parameter_date AS SELECT '2024-02-25'::DATE AS param_date;
```

and then JOIN this table into your later statement in the FROM clause.  This does work and if you are reusing this date many times in many statement then this can be a fine way to go. Be aware that this does need to set up the data structures in the DB for a table so may not be the best in all cases.

There are likely many other ways to address this inside and outside of Redshift but hopefully this gives you some ideas.